# how to compile just one equation

Tags: compiling, winedt

I am working with WinEdt 6.0 and working with a long document, therefore, some times I would like to compile just one equation and get the pdf output of it, instead of running pdflatex that compiles the whole document.

I used to do so with previous versions of WinEdt but don´t findout how to do so with version 6.

This saves a lot of time!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy.

Just select the equation and use the command "Compile Selected" from the menu "Accessories" or click the corresponding button in the toolbar:

[image]

BTW: WinEdt 6 is quite old now and not maintained anymore. I suggest you to switch to version 8 (which has lots of new features).